# What does DNS address signifies in the router?

Tags: dns

Is DNS address in the router is the address that will be first looked up for DNS query?

I have the following DNS address -

```
124.40.244.3
and DNS gateway is 
124.40.244.90
```

What gateway means here? For DNS query, will it send the packet to DNS address or DNS gateway?

Comment: This is unclear.  There is no such thing as a "DNS gateway".  There is "default gateway" and "DNS servers", please clarify which IP goes with each.

Answer (score 2):

They are two different things:

1) Gateway is used for routing all traffic that is not on the same (local) network as your computer or device. (Note there is no such thing as DNS Gateway - only gateway)

2) The DNS server is address where all DNS request are going to be sent.

Now there might be a situation where if looking at home router you would see something like DNS forwarder - that would be in case where your router serves as DNS server for your local network and in that case it would be gateway as well DNS for your PCs.

Comment: How my router got the DNS server address? I bought a belkin router, and just plugged in the LAN CABLE, and Power cable. I only configure the SSID name and password. Rest was taken by Belkin software.

Comment: Is gateway IP address in nothing but my ISP - IP address?

Comment: Correct gateway IP is the IP address assigned by DHCP from your ISP

Answer (score 0):

If the router is distributing IP Addresses (DHCP server) for your network, the router usually hands outs it's address as ther DNS server. in that case, this DNS setting is the DNS server the router will access to resolve client DNS requests.  Since multiple routes & interfaces are possible within the router, I assume the gateway represents the IP address the router should use as the gateway for forwarding those requests DNS requests.